# Print Job Exception when adding job in PrintQueue

Tags: c#, printing, xps, printqueue

With this code:

```
PrintQueue pq;
using (var PS = new LocalPrintServer())
{
    pq = PS.GetPrinterQueue("HP Printer");
}

pq.AddJob("JobName 1", "C:\\Resources\\basic.xps", true, pq.DefaultPrintTicket.Clone());
```

I can successfully print files with some printers queue, but not with all my printers queue and I got **System.PrintJobException--Specified method is not supported**. *(The parameter PrintTicket here is by default, but I need this overload method in order to change this value).*

Also `PrintQueue.AddJob(string jobName, string filePath, bool fastCopy)` throws System.PrintJobException.

However using `PrintQueue.AddJob(string jobName)` instead of `PrintQueue.AddJob(string jobName, string filePath, bool fastCopy, PrintTicket printTicket)` it throws no exception, but the file to print cannot be specified.

Does every driver support the PrintQueue.AddJob()? Is anything missing?

Thanks a lot in advance.

**I finally solved it** using this instead of `pq.AddJob()`:

```
pq.UserPrintTicket = pq.DefaultPrintTicket.Clone(); // Whatever PrintTicket we need
pq.Commit();
string s;
using (StreamReader strReader = new StreamReader("C:\\Resources\\basic.xps")){
s = strReader.ReadToEnd();
}
 PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
 p.PrintPage += delegate(object sender1, PrintPageEventArgs e1)
 {
       e1.Graphics.DrawString(s, new Font("Times New Roman", 12), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new RectangleF(0, 0, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width, p.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height));

};
p.Print();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set `fastCopy = false` in `PrintQueue.AddJob(string jobName, string filePath, bool fastCopy)`